# Why is $xy\in(x^2,y)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> If $F$ is a field, the ideal $(x,y)$ is maximal in $F[x,y]$ and therefore prime. Furthermore $$(x,y)^2 \subsetneq (x^2,xy,y^2) \subsetneq (x^2,y) \subsetneq (x,y).$$

Question: How $(x^2,xy,y^2) \subset (x^2,y)$, i.e. how $xy \in (x^2,y)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $xy \in (y) \subseteq (x^2, y)$ as a multiple of $y$.